# Unity bug makes objects glitch with square patterns

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I am currently working on a simulation and for some reason my game objects keep glitching / flickering random square patterns, both in the scene and game view. I have attached images for reference (all the objects are meant to be a single color, no patterns).

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is not a glitch, your objects do not have UV.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you please specify what you mean with 'UV'?